# After ppa-purge, apt wants to un install my DE

Tags: package-management, ppa, 17.10

Ubuntu 17.10
I tried upgrading my graphics drivers using the oibaf PPA, but it flubbed on the libdrm requirements, saying it needed 2.85, but only had 2.83. tried a --fix-broken and got this:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libomxil-bellagio-bin libomxil-bellagio0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
29 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/62.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 24.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 141995 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.83-1) ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) over (2.4.83-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids', which is also in package libdrm-common 2.4.83-1
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.83-1) ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) over (2.4.83-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids', which is also in package libdrm-common 2.4.83-1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I then used ppa-purge to try and revert, but it errored:

```
sudo ppa-purge  ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: oibaf graphics-drivers
Package revert list generated:
 libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64/artful libdrm-amdgpu1:i386/artful

Disabling oibaf PPA from 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-artful.list
Updating packages lists
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libdrm-amdgpu1 is already the newest version (2.4.83-1).
libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 is already the newest version (2.4.83-1).
libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 set to manually installed.
Selected version '2.4.83-1' (Ubuntu:17.10/artful [amd64]) for 'libdrm-amdgpu1'
Selected version '2.4.83-1' (Ubuntu:17.10/artful [i386]) for 'libdrm-amdgpu1:i386'
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) but 2.4.83-1 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) but 2.4.83-1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
/usr/sbin/ppa-purge: line 191: aptitude: command not found
Warning:  Something went wrong, packages may not have been reverted
```

And now if I try to do a --fix-broken I get this:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bogofilter bogofilter-bdb bogofilter-common evolution-common libbsd0:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libgsl23 libgslcblas0 libllvm5.0:i386 libmspack0 libnm-glib-vpn1 libomxil-bellagio-bin
  libomxil-bellagio0 libpciaccess0:i386 libpst4 libsensors4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:i386 libva-wayland1
  libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386
  libxshmfence1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libytnef0 network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openvpn
  network-manager-ssh network-manager-vpnc python-cairo python-gobject-2 python-gpgme python-gtk2 sshpass
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgl1 libglvnd0 libglx0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aisleriot apport-gtk apturl baobab caribou cheese chrome-gnome-shell dconf-editor deja-dup eog evince evolution
  evolution-data-server evolution-ews evolution-plugin-bogofilter evolution-plugin-pstimport evolution-plugins
  file-roller firefox gcr gdm3 gedit gir1.2-caribou-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0
  gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0
  gir1.2-mutter-1 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
  gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gjs gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-calendar gnome-control-center
  gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-keyring gnome-logs gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin
  gnome-session-canberra gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-snap gnome-sudoku
  gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-tweak-tool gnome-user-docs gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share
  google-chrome-stable gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-vaapi gucharmap ibus ibus-gtk3 ibus-table
  language-selector-gnome libappindicator3-1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcaribou0
  libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-3.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcolord-gtk1 libcryptui0a libedataserverui-1.2-1
  libegl1-mesa libevdocument3-4 libevolution libevview3-3 libgail-3-0 libgbm1 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgjs0g libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgnome-autoar-gtk-0-0 libgnome-bluetooth13
  libgnome-desktop-3-12 libgnome-games-support-1-2 libgnomekbd8 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgspell-1-1
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgtkspell3-3-0
  libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgweather-3-6 libindicator3-7 libmutter-1-0 libnautilus-extension1a libnm-gtk0 libnma0
  libpeas-1.0-0 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 librhythmbox-core10 libtotem0
  libvte-2.91-0 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwnck-3-0 libyelp0 mousetweaks mutter nautilus
  nautilus-dropbox nautilus-share network-manager-gnome network-manager-openconnect-gnome network-manager-openvpn-gnome
  network-manager-pptp-gnome network-manager-ssh-gnome network-manager-vpnc-gnome notification-daemon pinentry-gnome3
  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins seahorse seahorse-daemon shotwell simple-scan
  software-properties-gtk steam:i386 system-config-printer system-config-printer-common thunderbird
  thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us totem totem-plugins transmission-gtk
  ubuntu-docs ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session ubuntu-software update-manager update-notifier usb-creator-gtk
  vino xdg-user-dirs-gtk xorg xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xwayland yelp zenity
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgl1 libglvnd0 libglx0
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 203 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
29 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 160 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,026 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n                  
Abort.
```

Yikes! It wants to uninstall my entire DE! Now I do have ubuntu-desktop removed (to remove the dock). I can't install anything right now without it wanting to remove EVERYTHING. I though ppa-purge was supposed to prevent this kind of thing. Any advice?

edit: I should also state I am running this on a Dell xps 13, so full Intel CPU and GPU. I also went through and did an apy install ubuntu-desktop^ to try and make surer all the packages for the DE were marked for install, but it hasn't made any visible difference.

edit2: @George since it was too long for a comment:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up mutter-common (3.26.1-2ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.54.1-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 depends on libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a); however:
  Version of libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 on system is 2.4.83-1.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-dri:i386:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 depends on libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a); however:
  Version of libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 on system is 2.4.83-1.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libglapi-mesa:amd64 (17.4~git1710301149.134a40~gd~a) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:i386 (17.4~git1710301149.134a40~gd~a) ...
Setting up skypeforlinux (8.9.0.1) ...
Setting up libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) ...
Setting up libdrm2:i386 (2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) ...
Setting up gnome-shell-common (3.26.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) ...
Setting up libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 depends on libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 7.2); however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-glx:i386:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 depends on libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 7.2); however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) ...
Setting up libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Setting up libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) ...
Setting up libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-1) ...
Setting up libgles2-mesa:amd64 (17.4~git1710301149.134a40~gd~a) ...
Setting up libpoppler68:amd64 (0.57.0-2ubuntu4.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libegl1-mesa:amd64:
 libegl1-mesa:amd64 depends on libgl1-mesa-dri (= 17.4~git1710301149.134a40~gd~a); however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libegl1-mesa:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libpoppler-glib8:amd64 (0.57.0-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up poppler-utils (0.57.0-2ubuntu4.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmutter-1-0:amd64:
 libmutter-1-0:amd64 depends on libegl1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) | libegl1-x11; however:
  Package libegl1-mesa:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package libegl1-x11 is not installed.
  Package libegl1-mesa:amd64 which provides libegl1-x11 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmutter-1-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgbm1:amd64:
 libgbm1:amd64 depends on libgl1-mesa-dri (= 17.4~git1710301149.134a40~gd~a); however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgbm1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell depends on libmutter-1-0 (>= 3.25.90); however:
  Package libmutter-1-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libxatracker2:amd64 (17.4~git1710301149.134a40~gd~a) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64:
 libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 depends on libegl1-mesa (= 17.4~git1710301149.134a40~gd~a); however:
  Package libegl1-mesa:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-mutter-1:amd64:
 gir1.2-mutter-1:amd64 depends on libmutter-1-0 (= 3.26.1-2ubuntu2); however:
  Package libmutter-1-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gir1.2-mutter-1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mutter:
 mutter depends on libmutter-1-0 (>= 3.25.90); however:
  Package libmutter-1-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mutter (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
 libegl1-mesa:amd64
 libmutter-1-0:amd64
 libgbm1:amd64
 gnome-shell
 libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64
 gir1.2-mutter-1:amd64
 mutter
```

Final Edit: I finally managed to fix it. I used `sudo dpkg --purge libdrm-common`, re-enabled the PPA, updated, then ran `sudo apt upgrade` and it upgraded fine. It now no longer tries to uninstall my DE, and the packages no longer throw errors.

Comment: Did you try `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` then  `sudo apt update`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried that,  no change on the fix-broken. 

I think I am going to try focusing on fixing these errors, because they are what is hanging up the oibaf PPA:

    libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) but 2.4.83-1 is installed
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) but 2.4.83-1 is installed

Comment: Now do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Blerg. ok so the heart of this is the libdrm-common package. I can't at this point do anything. fix-broken fails because it won't override that sub package, and I can't remove libdrm-common because libgl1-mesa-dri is saying it has unmet dependencies (because of that package). If I remove the PPA, it wants to uninstall my whole DE.

Comment: Let me get you correctly, after adding the `ppa` you did update, then installed driver or upgraded existing driver?

Comment: @George: Thanks for your help. Yes I added the ppa, told it to update. It errored on libdrm-amdgpu1. I tried removing the ppa using ppa-purge, and that put me in my current pickle. I am posting the output from dpkg above, since it was too long for a comment.

Comment: You did right to post add into your question, that's the right thing to do...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apt-get stopped working because of dependancy issue - libegl1-mesa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551783/apt-get-stopped-working-because-of-dependancy-issue-libegl1-mesa)

Comment: It looks like the maintainer has been made aware via his forum on [phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/opengl-vulkan-mesa-gallium3d/24959-updated-and-optimized-ubuntu-free-graphics-drivers/page175?50038-Updated-and-Optimized-Ubuntu-Free-Graphics-Drivers=). No resolution yet though.

Comment: @George: I finally managed to fix it. I used `sudo dpkg --purge libdrm-common`, re-enabled the PPA, then ran `sudo apt upgrade` and it upgraded fine. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
sudo dpkg --purge libdrm-common
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```